# How to verify Switch widget's state in a flutter test?

Tags: user-interface, dart, flutter

Is there a flutter matcher that can verify a state of a [Switch](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Switch-class.html) widget? I can find the widget by key using `find.byKey(myKey)`. So if there was a matcher like `isToggled(state)`, I would verify my widget's state by writing something like this in my test:

```
expect(find.byKey(myKey), isToggled(true))
```

Is there a matcher like that? How do I verify toggled state?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [byWidgetPredicate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/CommonFinders/byWidgetPredicate.html) method of the [CommonFinders](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/CommonFinders-class.html) class to specify the type of any widget and so examine the state of that type. So for your specific example you can simply do:

```
final finder = find.byWidgetPredicate(
  (widget) => widget is Switch && widget.key == myKey && widget.value == true,
  description: 'Switch is enabled');

expect(finder, findsOneWidget);
```

Answer (score 2):

WIDGET

```
class SwitchWdt extends StatelessWidget {
  bool isSwitched = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Switch(
        key: Key('widget_key'),
        value: isSwitched,
        onChanged: (_){});
  }
}
```

TEST

```
final Finder switchFinder = find.byKey(Key('widget_key'));
final switchWdt = tester.widget<Switch>(switchFinder);
expect(switchWdt.value, false);
```

Comment: This si the simplest answer ! Thanks @stark

Answer (score 1):

There are none. But you can make your own, so here's one:

```
class _IsToggled extends CustomMatcher {
  _IsToggled(dynamic matcher)
      : super('Check if a switch if enabled or not', 'isToggled', matcher);

  @override
  Object featureValueOf(dynamic actual) {
    final finder =actual as Finder;
    final result = finder.evaluate().single as Switch;

    return result.value;
  }
}

Matcher isToggled(bool value) => _IsToggled(value);
```

Comment: if you can please update this with a sample code on the usage? It will be more helpful to learn the technique for me?